# Which scripture describes Hanuman as Brahman?

Tags: scripture, hanuman

Hanuman is a well-known god of Sanathana Dharma. He is popularised as a dootha for Rama. But, many believe that Hanuman is a saguna brahman.

Is it true that Hanuman is a Brahman? Which verses from scriptures describe Hanuman as ParaBrahman?

Comment: Tattriyaupanishad describes Hanuman aka vayu as brahman in shanti mantra.. "Namasthye Vayu thaavamayva prathaksham brahmasi"

Answer (score 3):

> **स सर्वरुपः सर्वज्ञ सृष्टिस्थितिकरोऽवतु।
> स्वयं ब्रह्मा स्वयं विष्णु साक्षाद
> देवो महेश्वरः।।**

> (नारद पुराण पुर्व तृतीय पाद ७८. २४-२५)

> हनुमान सभी रुपों में अभिव्यक्त हैं , वे सर्व ज्ञानी है तथा वे ही ब्रह्मा रुप में जगत के रचयिता, विष्णु रुप में संचालन तथा महादेव के रुप में संहार करते हैं।

Translation:

Hanuman is manifested in all forms, he is all-knowing and he is the creator of the world in the form of Brahma, the operator in the form of Vishnu and the destroyer in the form of Mahadev.

Comment: Do you have link to this chapter in the Purana? Interested in the context as the shloka listed here doesn't mention Hanuman

Comment: I don't have link, sorry 